# Facebook SWF Game feed posting doesn't work

Tags: facebook, feed, facebook-opengraph, game-development

I've been trying for the past couple days to get a small swf game working via a feed post to my wall (per the instructions at the Facebook Developers site). So far, I've had no success, despite having everything appear correctly in the OG Debugger. The metadata I'm using to generate the feed post is the following:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb"> 
<meta property="fb:app_id"       content="157726317622339" />
<meta property="og:type"         content="game" />
<meta property="og:url"          content="http://devapplatform.com:3557/site/feed_game/" />
<meta property="og:title"        content="It Or Miss Mini Game" />
<meta property="og:description"  content="Sebastian submitted to It or Miss, Come vote for them here!" />
<meta property="og:image"        content="http://devapplatform.com:3558/images/catSurprise.jpg" />
<meta property="og:video"        content="http://devapplatform.com:3558/images/catTest.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:width"  content="398" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="299" />
<meta property="og:video:type"   content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
</head>
```

This code is stored on the following web page:
http://devapplatform.com:3557/site/feed_game/

If you want to test this code to see exactly what it's posting, you can simply launch my test app (make sure HTTPS is turned off for your account - I can't have HTTPS enabled on this app due to technical limitations of my environment. Rest assured HTTPS IS enabled on the production version of this app). The feed dialog should appear immediately after launch, during the loading process:
http://apps.facebook.com/itgirlsb/

DISCLAIMER: These links aren't guaranteed to always be available, due to them being hosted on a local test environment which gets powered off in the evenings PSD.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see page or the image / SWF to test, but try these:

1. Your images should be at least 90x90px, otherwise we won't show the image, so there's nothing to click. Ideally make them 200x200px or more.
2. If you want the embed to work for anyone who is using secure browsing (https://www.facebook.com) then you need to host your SWF on a secure host. If it's on an http host, we can only embed it for users who have secure browsing disabled; otherwise the browser would throw mixed content warnings.